# Scroll only specific element with page scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to move the scrolling bar from div2

`|         div1         |          |`
`|--------------------- |          |`
`|                 |SCRL|          |`
`|                 |SCRL|   div3   |`
`|                 |SCRL|          |`
`|    div2         |SCRL|          |`
`|                 |SCRL|          |`
`|                 |SCRL|          |`
`|                 |SCRL|          |`

into outside to the whole interface like this.

`|       div1           |          ||SCRL|`
`|----------------------|          ||SCRL|`
`|                      |          ||SCRL|`
`|                      |  div3    ||SCRL|`
`|                      |          ||SCRL|`
`|    div2              |          ||SCRL|`
`|                      |          ||SCRL|`
`|                      |          ||SCRL|`
`|                      |          ||SCRL|`

And when we scoll the new scroll bar, div2 will be shifted as normal.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin:0px;
}
.div3{
  float:right;
  height:480px;
  width:28%;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.div1 { 
  position:fixed;
  width:70%;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.div2{
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:200px;
  width:70%;
  height: 280px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div3">div 3</div>
  <div class="div1">div 1</div>
  <div class="div2"style="overflow-y: scroll">
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
    div2 <br> div2 <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/sep1u4jf/

many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `position:fixed` for **both** your top and right elements.

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

/* LAYOUT */
#top{
  position: fixed; z-index:1;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 70%; height: 99px;
  background: #0ff;
}
#right{
  position: fixed; z-index:1;
  right: 0; top: 0;
  width: 30%; height: 100vh;
  background: #0bf;
}
#bottom{
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 99px;
  width: 70%; min-height: calc(100vh - 99px);
  background: #f0b;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div id="top">top fixed</div>
  <div id="right">right fixed</div>

  <div id="bottom">
    <p style="height:1200px; border:4px dashed #000; margin:0;"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.S: I used `99px` `height` and `top` for **demo**. Replace all `99px` with `480px` or whatever you need.

Comment: many thanks, Roko ! super answer ! Sorry I lack of 4 more reputations to make upvote successful :(

Comment: @gnase glad I could help you. Make sure to format properly your questions with code, answer on questions and you'll get rep in no-time :) Happy coding.

Comment: gotcha :). Thanks again !

Comment: Do I need necessary to use code snippet instead of just giving fiddle link in my next questions ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if your intention is to keep the content inside a fixed height? If it isn't, you can just to set the height of the container to 100%/remove it entirely and your elements will scroll correctly.

You will have to use relative/absolute positioning with this also.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/sep1u4jf/3/

```
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:200px;
    width:70%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid purple;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you. But I need to keep the layout as original. If we do like that, then the height of div2 is too large, it breaks the layout. :(